# Ember Component loads store data

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Which life cycle do you think is the most appropriate place to load `store` data in `Ember.Component`?

I’m loading data asynchronously. That’s why I’m not loading the real data from `route`, but its meta-data?

For example. I'm loading a list of books, thats based on Author's `name`, and a list of `publisher`. (This is just an illustration).

I get a a list of authors, and a list of publishers.

Codes:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      authors: this.store.findAll('author'),
      publishers: this.store.findAll('publisher')
    });
  }
})
```

After fetching `authors` and `publishers` from the `route`, now we can do another query, namely `this.store.find('book', {author, publisher})` to get a book.

I just wanted to ask to see which life cycle in Ember.Component is more appropriate to fetch such data asynchronously.

**Update:**

This issues can be solved by putting the loading logics in the following 3 ways:

1. In `setupController` inside `route`.
2. In `model()` hook of `route`
3. In component life cycle.

After consideration (reading and discussing with colleagues), I think Component should be putting result, not the logics. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to chain it.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      m1s: this.store.findAll('meta1'),
      m2s: this.store.findAll('meta2')
    }).then( ({m1, m2}) => {

      let data = [];
      m1s.forEach( (m1) => {
        m2s.forEach( (m2) => {    
          this.store.query('modelName', {
              m1.get('id'),
              m2.get('id')
          });

        });

      });

    });
  }
}),
```

You might need to write your own `adapter` and `serializer` though.

Answer (score 2):

The `init()` hook is where you want to make the request for data.

```
import Component from 'ember-component';
import injectService from 'ember-service/inject';

export default Component.extend({
  store: injectService(),

  posts: [],

  init(){
    this._super(...arguments);

    this._getPosts();
  },

  _getPosts() {
    this.get('store').findAll('post').then((posts) => {

      // because this is async you need to guard against the component 
      // being destroyed before the api call has finished because 
      // because `this.set` will throw an error.
      if (this.isDestroyed) { return; } 

      this.set('posts', posts);
  }
});
```

Comment: Any reference? I saw people load data in `didInsertElement` hook, though I knew `didInsertElement` is supposedly to [integrate with 3rd party libraries](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/). Thank you.

Comment: Did that work for you Alan? you want to start the request for data as soon as possible.

Comment: Because this is not the "Ember Way" of gathering data this is not documented. The ember way is to get the data in the route and pass it to the component.

Comment: I get your point, and would have done it this way. Since this component actually has an dependencies, I'm using `Ember.RSVP` chaining in the route to fetch the first meta-data, then chain with another promise data. See my answer in this thread